# Android CSS layout will not use full screen width

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I am developing a mobile website at the moment. You can see it here: `http://m.mayojobs.ie`. In a nutshell the website lists job adverts, a search menu, and a "load more jobs" button.

The layout looks nice in iPhone (Safari & Chrome), but for some reason in Android each job listing is only using about one third of the screen. It should not be doing this.

Also, the Google Advert at the bottom of the screen is supposed to be 300 x 250, but for some reason is tiny.

I have been trying to solve this for days but can't figure it out.

If any of you know why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks you.

Comment: Get yourself a viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Not related to your problem but you should make sure that jQuery and MooTools aren't conflicting. You only seem to be using the $.(''); selector. Maybe consider using the jQuery.(''); selector for your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see in the browser settings the zoom probably is at 'far'.

You could try also with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Oh my god... I love you! Thank you, that has solved the issue for me.